# Where to start in Phonegap 3 folder structure

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have been using Phonegap 2.9 and saw that they have the latest version 3.0. I have installed it on my PC but the latest folder structure is confusing for Android development. Can anybody help me where to put the HTML files and relevant JAVA plugins and packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new project in cordova 3.0 and simply put your www folder to assets. Also you cant use old packages, have to install those using CLI(Command Line Interface). Go through this [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20Android), they are well documented it.

[image: folder structure for Android]

[image: folder structure for Ios]

Comment: So for every target OS/platform you have to copy the html? Or do you work with symlinks? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the above answer is wrong. You have to put your code in the www folder, and only the platform-specific files in "merges".
I'm quoting from http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/:

"you will see another www folder created within each of the platform folders (ie: yourprojectroot/platforms/ios/www for iOS and yourprojectroot/platforms/android/assets/www for android). DO NOT use this folder directly as it is going to be overwritten every time those commands are run. You should always work from the root www folder and use the merges folder for changes specific to a platform."

Comment: I think this makes more sense than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must put html files, javascript and CSS in assets/ folder.Then you can put start file (index.html) in config.xml or in your main Activity.